# Find the limit of the sum of normal pdf's

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-distributions

How to find the limit of the sum of Gaussian probability distribution functions?

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}
    \sum_{k=1}^N
        \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi k}}
        \exp\left(-\frac{(N-k\mu)^2 }{2k \sigma^2} \right)
$$

... this is a paraphrase of

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}
    \sum_{k=1}^N P(x = N \: | \: k \mu, \sigma \sqrt{k})
$$

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the subject? Update your question and we will be help to guide you